# Minimum / maximum required profit on a day

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have data as under

```
Name    Code    Code    Date    Profit          Name        Maximum Minimum
A   2400    1/11/2016   38500           A   nil 2100
A   2300    1/14/2016   26750           B   aaa 1260
A   2200    1/14/2016   21250           C   nil 95
A   2300    1/11/2016   19250                   
A   2250    1/14/2016   14000                   
A   2100    1/14/2016   11750                   
B   1220    1/15/2016   750                 
B   1280    1/11/2016   4875                    
B   1360    1/12/2016   4875                    
B   1380    1/11/2016   4500                    
B   bbb 1/11/2016   3375                    
B   1280    1/12/2016   2250                    
B   1340    1/11/2016   2250                    
B   1340    1/14/2016   2250                    
B   aaa 1/15/2016   50000                   
B   1260    1/15/2016   0                   
C   85  1/14/2016   324000                  
C   85  1/13/2016   282000                  
C   85  1/11/2016   246000                  
C   95  1/15/2016   200                 
C   90  1/12/2016   156000                  
C   90  1/14/2016   138000
```

In the above I want to write a formula such that for example name "A" -search maximum profit , if that profit happened to be on date the maximum among the dates, then give code as mentioned in column two. For example for name "A" maximum profit is 38500 which happens on 1/11/2016 which is not latest date among the date column against name "A" so output is nil. Similarly I want to find the minimum for example for B the minimum profit is 0 (zero) and this happens to be on the date latest in the date so it prints 1260. Also the data is being added every day and the code column may be a number or text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was using its [LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) and [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) subfunctions to directly return the true numbers. If you need to return a text-based result, AGGREGATE must return the [ROW](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) number of the matching value and pass that to an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

In H2 as a standard formula,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,D:D )))/((A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=G2)*
     (C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=AGGREGATE(14, 6, C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))/(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=G2), 1))*
     (D$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=AGGREGATE(14, 6, D$2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))/(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=G2), 1))), 1))
    , "nil")
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: aggregate_max_min_stock_codes]

Comment: Thanks Sir, God Bless